# Is the OpenCV 3d Histogram 3 axis histogram?

Tags: opencv

What exactly is the 3d histogram returned from OpenCV's `calcHist()`?

For a 1d histogram I know that:
- the x axis represents my desired bins (for simplicity lets say 0-255 - grayscale colour values).
- the y axis represents the number of pixels that have that bin/colour value.

For a 3d histogram...am I correct that:
- There are 3 x axis arrays? One for each colour channel (in my case b,g,r)?
- There are 3 y axis arrays? One for each of the above?

OR

- There are still only 1 x and y axis. But the x axis represents a concatenation(?) of b*g*r and the y axis tells me how many pixels have the colour b*g*r?

If its the first scenario, does OpenCV have a way to:
- Produce a unique number to represent a colour (hexadecimal? or combine b*g*r)?
- Produce a histogram of a 3 channel image where the x axis bins represent the unique colour number above and y axis tells me how many pixels have that colour?
- Presumably this is alot more computationally efficient than having a 3d histogram with 255 bins?

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV's `calcHist()` can calculate the histograms of an arbitrary** number of images/channels. The returned histogram has as many axes as the number of channels in the input image, and each axis has as many values as bins designated for that channel. For instance, say you had a RGBD image; that is, four-channels: one for red, blue, green, and another for depth. If you wanted to for whatever reason calculate the histogram of such an image, OpenCV lets you:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lane.jpg')
img = np.dstack([img, img[:, :, 0]])
print('Input image shape:', img.shape)
n_channels = img.shape[2]
channels = list(range(n_channels))
sizes = [8,]*n_channels
ranges = [0, 255]*n_channels
hist = cv2.calcHist(img, channels, None, sizes, ranges)
print('Output histogram shape: ', hist.shape)
```

> Input image shape: (540, 960, 4)
>
> Output histogram shape:  (8, 8, 8, 8)

Note in the line `np.dstack([img, img[:, :, 0]])` I'm simply adding the first channel to the end of the image as a fourth channel. You could modify the program to run on an image with a channel depth of 9, and get an output 9D histogram:

```
img = cv2.imread('lane.jpg')
img = np.dstack([img, img, img])
print('Input image shape:', img.shape)
n_channels = img.shape[2]
channels = list(range(n_channels))
sizes = [8,]*n_channels
ranges = [0, 255]*n_channels
hist = cv2.calcHist(img, channels, None, sizes, ranges)
print('Output histogram shape: ', hist.shape)
```

> Input image shape: (540, 960, 9)
>
> Output histogram shape:  (8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)

Here the only modification was again to the `dstack` line where I simply stacked the image three times to create an image with 9 channels.

For a multichannel array, you're thinking of the axes a little wrongly. Instead of calling them `x`, `y`, etc, you should just think of them as `bins` from each channel, i.e., `ch1bins, ch2bins, ...` and so on. If you take the histogram of a single-channel image, then sure; when I *plot* them, the `x`-axis has your bins and the `y`-axis has your counts, but that's just a way to plot them. Really you have an array of bins, and an array of counts. If you plot the histogram of a two-channel image and visualized it with a 3D bar chart, then the `x`-axis has bins, but so does the `y`-axis, and the `z` axis in that case has the counts. The `x` axis would have the bins of the first channel, the `y` axis would have bins of the second channel. If you had a three-channel image, then to visualize in a plot, all three axes are bins corresponding to each channel, and thus you'd have to visualize the quantity in each bin with something else, like the size of a marker for that bin, or you'd have to color the markers based on their intensity or something.

The OpenCV [docs for `calcHist()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d) give an example of a 2D histogram (that is, two-channel) where you can analyze a histogram of hue and saturation values. What that means is that for a given range of hue and saturation values (say hue between 0 and 32, and saturation between 144 and 176), you can see the number of pixels that fall within that range.

For an example with 3D histograms, you can [check out some I've plotted](http://reynoldsalexander.com/3dhistplots.html). I didn't use OpenCV for the histograms because...I actually didn't know it could do 3D histograms until you asked this question. But `numpy` can do D-dimensional histograms all the same, like OpenCV. In these plots, the color of the marker corresponds to the actual color that bin represents, and the marker size somewhat corresponds to the number of values in each bin.

If I took a 3D histogram and let's just say we want to know the darker and lighter counts for each channel. So I'll just take a histogram with 2 bins of each channel. Then my bins would be:

- Channel 0: `[0, 127], [128, 255]`
- Channel 1: `[0, 127], [128, 255]`
- Channel 2: `[0, 127], [128, 255]`

Take a pixel with values `[0, 255, 0]`. That would correspond to being in bin 0 for channel 0, bin 1 for channel 1, and bin 0 for channel 3. How many total possibilities are there? A pixel could be in bins:

- 0, 0, 0
- 0, 0, 1
- 0, 1, 0
- 0, 1, 1
- 1, 0, 0
- 1, 0, 1
- 1, 1, 0
- 1, 1, 1

So there's 8 possibilities. If I plot all the RGB values in 3-space, then splitting each of these axes in two gives 8 different histogram bins. Then I simply count the number in each of these 8 bins, and that's the histogram. So looking at the above list, this simple histogram would tell me how many dark pixels there are (corresponding to bins 0, 0, 0), how many light pixels there are (corresponding to 1, 1, 1), how many mostly green pixels there are (0, 1, 0), etc. And indeed this is what OpenCV gives:

```
img = cv2.imread('lane.jpg')
print('Input image shape:', img.shape)
n_channels = img.shape[2]
channels = list(range(n_channels))
sizes = [2, 2, 2]
ranges = [0, 255]*n_channels
hist = cv2.calcHist(img, channels, None, sizes, ranges)
print('Output histogram shape: ', hist.shape)
```

> Input image shape: (540, 960, 3)
>
> Output histogram shape:  (2, 2, 2)

The whole point of multichannel histograms is to figure out how many pixels lie within some value range independently for each channel. Hopefully this post has cleared some of that up!

**Note: don't use small bin sizes with a high number of channels...you'll run out of memory quickly.

Comment: I love your plots in Jupyter. I couldn't find how to code them to run from the command-line, as matplotlib is way too slow and mayavi's color map [is associated to a scalar and not an RGB triplet](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_custom_colormap.html#example-custom-colormap). Have you coded a 4D histogram in OpenCV since your answer?

Comment: @miguelmorin If you create the figure object, you can simply write the figure to HTML and then view it interactively later, outside of a notebook. So you can generate them from the command line. Check out this section in the docs: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started-with-chart-studio/#initialization-for-offline-plotting (note, these apis have changed around a few times so there's different ways to do this if you have older versions). There's other rendering options, too: https://plot.ly/python/renderers/

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks! I want to code a similar histogram in HSV and Lab spaces, got stuck at the `np.meshgrid()` step, and asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426380/how-to-plot-3d-histogram-of-hsv-and-cielab-values) with no answers. Could you have a look?