# How to plot 3D histogram of HSV and CIELAB values?

Tags: python, numpy, colors, plotly, histogram

I want to code a 3D histogram to develop a clustering algorithm in CIELAB space. I started with the [3D histogram in RGB space](http://reynoldsalexander.com/3dhistplots.html), which I found [through this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498041/is-the-opencv-3d-histogram-3-axis-histogram), and expanded to HSV as a springboard to CIELAB. I checked that the labels and values work for RGB images. I got most of the way there but a few things are off for HSV.

Here is my refactored version of the code:

```py
# Histogram and plotly code from
# http://reynoldsalexander.com/3dhistplots.html
# and non-notebook plotting from
# https://plot.ly/python/getting-started-with-chart-studio/#initialization-for-offline-plotting

import bisect
import itertools
import os

import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

def plot_3d_hist(img, bin_size, model = "rgb"):

    h, w, num_channels = img.shape

    if isinstance(img, np.uint8):
        max_range = 255
    elif isinstance(img, np.uint16):
        max_range = 65535
    elif isinstance(img, np.float):
        max_range = 1.0
    else:
        max_range = np.amax(img)

    # generate indices and histogram
    ranges = ([0, max_range], [0, max_range], [0, max_range])
    bin_sizes = (bin_size, bin_size, bin_size)
    bin_range = np.arange(bin_size)

    # I don't know why this mesh is ordered this way, but it works with the test
    # images in BGR
    ch2, ch1, ch3 = np.meshgrid(bin_range, bin_range, bin_range)

    ch3 = ch3.ravel()*255/bin_size
    ch2 = ch2.ravel()*255/bin_size
    ch1 = ch1.ravel()*255/bin_size

    hist = np.histogramdd(img.reshape((h*w, num_channels)), bins=bin_sizes, range=ranges)[0]
    hist = hist.ravel()
    ch3, ch2, ch1, hist = ch3[hist>0], ch2[hist>0], ch1[hist>0], hist[hist>0]

    # map histogram amounts to marker sizes
    marker_sizes = [1, 5, 10, 16, 25]
    cut_size = int(np.ceil(hist.size/len(marker_sizes)))
    cuts = list(itertools.islice(sorted(hist), cut_size, None, cut_size))
    assign_marker_size = lambda val : marker_sizes[bisect.bisect(cuts, val)]
    hist_marker_sizes = list(map(assign_marker_size, hist))

    # colors from the image
    if "rgb" == model:
        colors = [f'rgb({ch3[i]}, {ch2[i]}, {ch1[i]})' for i in range(len(hist))]
        labels = ("red (x)", "green (y)", "blue (z)")
    elif "hsv" == model:
        colors = ["hsv(%d, %2.2f%%, %2.2f%%)" % (ch3[i] * 360 / 256,
                                                ch2[i] * 100 / 256,
                                                ch1[i] * 100 / 256) for i in range(len(hist))]
        labels = ("hue (x)", "saturation (y)", "value (z)")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Uncoded model: %s" % model)

    # plotly 
    scatter = go.Scatter3d(
        x=ch3, y=ch2, z=ch1, mode='markers',
        marker=dict(size=hist_marker_sizes, color=colors, opacity=1))
    layout = go.Layout(
        scene=dict(
            xaxis=dict(title=labels[0], range=[0, max_range]),
            yaxis=dict(title=labels[1], range=[0, max_range]),
            zaxis=dict(title=labels[2], range=[0, max_range])),
        margin=dict(r=0, b=0, l=0, t=0))

    return go.Figure(data=[scatter], layout=layout)

def random_dots(h, w, channel):
    return (200 if channel else 0) + (56 if channel else 255) * np.random.rand(h, w)

def random_image(truncate_channels = []):
    """Generate a random image with 3 channels. If truncate_channels is not empty, the
    random distribution will be over the high values of that channel.
    """
    h = w = 256
    img = np.zeros((h, w, 3))

    img[:, :, 0] = random_dots(h, w, 0 in truncate_channels)
    img[:, :, 1] = random_dots(h, w, 1 in truncate_channels)
    img[:, :, 2] = random_dots(h, w, 2 in truncate_channels)

    return img

def main(filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/result.html")):

    # Generate random images with focus on each of the channels
    img_channel0 = random_image([0])
    img_channel1 = random_image([1])
    img_channel2 = random_image([2])

    # for RGB, channels are BGR, and all these work as I expect
    #pio.write_html(plot_3d_hist(img_channel0, 32, model = "rgb"), file = filepath)  # focus on blue
    #pio.write_html(plot_3d_hist(img_channel1, 32, model = "rgb"), file = filepath)  # focus on green
    #pio.write_html(plot_3d_hist(img_channel2, 32, model = "rgb"), file = filepath)  # focus on red

    # For HSV, I couldn't understand it
    pio.write_html(plot_3d_hist(img_channel1, 32, model = "hsv"), file = filepath)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

The commented lines produce histograms focused on blue, green, and red:

[image: Random histogram truncated to blue]

[image: Random histogram truncated to green]

[image: Random histogram truncated to red]

The last uncommented line, with a random histogram truncated to the high values of channel 1, produces an image that seems truncated to hue:

[image: Random histogram truncated to second channel on HSV model]

(The colors are missing magenta near the top value of hue and colors seem too white at the top value of value, but I don't really mind, since for CIELAB I'll have to convert to RGB anyway.)

I suspect it's related to the channels being re-ordered after calling `np.meshgrid()`. In my version this is:

```py
ch2, ch1, ch3 = np.meshgrid(bin_range, bin_range, bin_range)
```

Why does this code work for RGB but in HSV it is channel 1 and not channel 0 that encodes hue?

### Update (4 February 2020)

For the ordering of the channels, the comments by @alkasm solved it.

For the color, it seems a bug in Plotly in dealing with `hsv()` specifiers with an angle above 240. For example, this simple code produces a red dot with `hsv(0, 100%, 50%)` and a blue dot with `hsv(359, 100%, 50%)`, when both should have a very similar color:

```py
def bug():

    max_range = 255
    ch1 = [128]
    ch2 = [128]
    ch3 = [128]
    color = "hsv(359, 100%, 50%)"
    scatter = go.Scatter3d(
            x=ch1, y=ch2, z=ch3, mode='markers',
            marker=dict(size=50, color=color, opacity=1))

    layout = go.Layout(
        scene=dict(
            xaxis=dict(title="x", range=[0, max_range]),
            yaxis=dict(title="y", range=[0, max_range]),
            zaxis=dict(title="z", range=[0, max_range])),
        margin=dict(r=0, b=0, l=0, t=0))

    return go.Figure(data=[scatter], layout=layout)


def main(filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/result.html")):

    pio.write_html(bug(), file = filepath)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Result with `"hsv(0, 100%, 50%)"`:

[image: Result with `"hsv(0, 100%, 50%)"]

Result with `"hsv(359, 100%, 50%)"`:

[image: Result with <code>"hsv(359, 100%, 50%)"</code>]

Comment: 1. Use immutable, not mutable values for default arguments (i.e. use `truncate_values=()` instead of `=[]` in `random_image()`); more [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). 2. The `meshgrid` ordering 2, 1, 3 is because `meshgrid` assumes you want Cartesian `(x, y)` ordering, instead of `(i, j)` array indexing. The keyword argument `indexing='ij'` fixes this. Alternatively swapping the two arrays as I did works too, but is less clear. Check the [`meshgrid` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for more.

Comment: Where you set the `colors` variable, I used `ch3, ch2, ch1` ordering because RGB has to be specified in that order, but my image was BGR. Probably bad form in my code. The order of HSV *is* of course 1, 2, 3, so your string interpolation with `(ch3[i] * 360 / 256, ch2[i] * 100 / 256, ch1[i] * 100 / 256)` should have the channel orders 1, 2, 3. I think that may be your issue, but not sure.

Comment: You have your axes backwards in your call to `Scatter3d`: `x=ch3, y=ch2, z=ch1` should be 1, 2, 3 order. Not sure why you aren't getting the full range of hue values, but I don't think it's a plotly bug, something just isn't being scaled right likely.

Comment: You are right, and I had missed that part about the string interpolation and the axes. For HSV, I now have `x=ch1, y=ch2, z=ch3`, and I deleted my update and comment. Regarding the full range, I can't get plotly to display magenta: I get the following colors with `hsv(N, 100%, 50%)`: red at N=0, yellow at N=60, lime green at N=120, cyan at N=180, and blue at N=240, 270, 300, 330, and 360. I should get magenta at N=300 and I don't.

Comment: Yeah it should definitely wrap back around to red. Your max range goes to 255, but your color scaling should map first channel values of 255 in your array to 360 in the HSV. There's quite a few lines which use the `255` value on channel 1 though, so I would be suspect of that. Especially `ch1 = ch1.ravel()*255/bin_size` --- IIRC this is telling only to have buckets up to the value of 255, but you want buckets past that to 360.

Comment: The 255 is bound by the 0-255 in the encoding of the image in 8-bit unsigned integers. I added an update that shows the bug in Plotly with colors.

Comment: @alkasm I resorted to converting the HSV color space back to RGB with OpenCV, which I needed to do for the CIELAB color space anyway, and that works. Can you post an answer on the `meshgrid` indexes, or shall I post my code along with the text in your first comment?